# Re-use "controller" code in sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

Like rails routes resources, I am looking to make a sinatra application share the same code between different routes.

For example, in a `company`, we have `divisions` and `divisions` have `departments`. An `employee` can belong to a `department` or `division`.

So, I would like `GET /divisons/:division_id/employees` and `GET /divisons/:division_id/departments/department_id/employees` share the same code since the business logic is nearly the same.

My idea is to init `@division` and `@department` before action and use a helper function in order to fetch employees. Is it ok like that or is there a wiser way?

Comment: A helper is good, you can also use a module mixin and add the similar behavior to both classes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used sinatra multiple_route which allowed me to have the same controller code for many routes.